# What does "taking a class at the Yarn Barn" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning

What is "*the Yarn Barn*" a reference to in this passage?

> Like a gangster rapper caught **taking a class at the Yarn Barn**, these
>   are the creatures who bring naught but shame unto themselves and all
>   who came before them.

Comment: The Yarn Barn is either a real or fictional reference to a location where knitting, crochet, etc, are taught. Something grandmas and hipster chicks do, and something a tough-guy macho gangster would be mortified about if his compatriots caught him participating in.

Comment: @DanBron You should make that an answer—it answers the question perfectly adequately.

Comment: @Janus I just feel weird posting formal answers which can't really be supported (i.e. "just take my word for it, I'm a native speaker"). This happens most in cases of interpretation, especially super-narrow questions like this.  Also, if I leave a paper trail of using the word "chick", when the Revolution comes, they'll put me against the wall.

Comment: @DanBron You could censor out the chick bit and—since this is indeed a question about interpretation of something that is nonstandard—just use as reference all those other native speakers who have decided to name their knitting/sewing shops and things The Yarn Barn. The question is essentially asking “What does a native speaker understand this to mean?”, and being a native speaker is perfectly reasonable and adequate justification for such a question. :-)

Comment: @Janus As you like...

Comment: I've never come across a _Yarn Barn_ before. It turns out there's one in Shaw, 10 minutes from where I live. Does that make me a tough-guy macho gangster? I _am_ a tenth dan in origami.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Yarn Barn is either a real or fictional reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20yarn%20barn%22&tbm=isch) to a location where yarn and related accessories are sold, and [knitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Knitting), [crochet](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Crochet), etc, are taught:

[image: Image of the interior of a Yarn Barn, with legend]

These activities are something [grandmothers and hipster girls](http://www.thrillist.com/travel/nation/hipster-cliches-how-to-spot-a-hipster-neighborhood) do:

[image: Screenshot of linked Thrillist article describing knitting as a grandma and hipster girl activity]

And so, by extension, ***something a tough-guy macho gangster would be mortified about*** if his compatriots caught him participating in.

Unless he wanted some really cool [bling](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bling&defid=13000):

[image: girl wearing a "heavy chain" around her neck, crocheted from yarn.]

[image: guy knitting an outfit on the subway]

Comment: +1 for the answer, and another +1 for the _really cool bling_, if I could! (I took the liberty of adding an UrbanDictionary link for _bling_.)